# sudo apt-get update command not working on linode

Tags: linode, ubuntu-15.10

I am unable to run package update command on my LINODE server `sudo apt-get update` as it gives following error (image below). It has been two days I am completely struck. I have not added any domain to my server yet and I am only using server IP address.

[image]

Comment: Looks like an issue with the DNS and some network issues?

Comment: what does `host mirrors.linode.com` or `dig mirrors.linode.com` is returning?

Comment: I would just to make sure DNS is working properly, overall networking, and that you didn't run out of disk space. Once the issue is fixed, you might need to clear Apt cache before running `sudo apt-get update` again.

Comment: Have you been able to fix this yet?